# Help me to revise mySQL query

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to check if a regulation's date reminder is today and  regulation's date end not yet passed then I do not want it to display. The problem is that the query that I made isn't working in mysql. Can anyone help me to revise my query?

Here is my query:

```
$query="select * from t_regulation where dt_reminder >= '$today' and dt_ended ='$today'"
```

Comment: The query looks correct, how is it not working? Syntax errors or is it producing an unexpected result? if the result is unexpected, are you sure that your conditions are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming that your dt_reminder columns type is DATETIME, and not some sort of timestap.

```
SELECT * FROM t_regulation WHERE DATE(dt_reminder) >= CURDATE() AND DATE(dt_ended) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do many funky things with date functions;

[Mysql date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Very frequently I run into the problem that my date variable is a string that is not properly formatted for the default date time stamp in Mysql.

Remember it should be 'yyyy-mm-dd' for this comparison.

Also, for since the 'date ended' has not yet passed, shouldn't it be:

$query="select * from t_regulation where dt_reminder >= '$today' and (dt_ended > '$today' or dt_ended is null)"